# ActiveMQ CMS Failover mechanism does not work

Tags: c++, exception, activemq-classic, failover, activemq-cpp

I am using ActiveMQ 5.10.2 and I am trying to test a failover scenario with C++ clients using Apache ActiveMQ CMS (activemq-cpp-library-3.9.5). The configuration for one of the two brokers is:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker-1" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" useJmx="true">

<managementContext>
   <managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/>
</managementContext>

<persistenceAdapter>
   <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>

<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector 
    name="broker1->broker2" 
    uri="static:(failover:(tcp://broker-2:61637))" 
    duplex="false" 
    decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
    networkTTL="2" 
    dynamicOnly="true">             
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>

<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire"  updateClusterClients="true" uri="tcp://broker-1:61636?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/> 
 </transportConnectors>
```

The client's URL is : `failover:(tcp://broker-1:61636,tcp://broker-2:616137)?reconnectSupported=true&timeout=3000`

After the producer starts to send the messages to the consumer, I kill the broker-1 expecting to see the transition to broker-2. Instead of this, I am getting the following error:

```
Thread 16: onException: Exception: type=JMSException, msg=DataInputStream::readLong - Reached EOF
Thread 16: onException: Terminating program...
```

My question is, if the problem is on the *onException* Method, or is something wrong with the configuration of the failover mechanism.

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you have a strong reason to stay with 5.10.x? Easier to troubleshoot against versions that are not more than 5 years old (5.10.2 was released Feb 2015). First next step would be to test against latest 5.15.x

Comment: Hi Justin thank you for your comment. I am going to update to 5.13.4 and I will check again.